# Scatter/Bubble plot not correctly plotting using rCharts and dimple.js

Tags: r, rcharts, dimple.js

I am trying to create the simplest of scatter charts using dimple and rCharts. I am curious if there is something I mis-understand about the `'scatter'` type. When I run this code, the y-axis values are off by factors of ten or larger--almost as if the scatter chart is acting as a stacked bar chart instead of a simple scatter plot. The sample data below mimics my data exactly.

```
testdat1 <- data.frame(Recommend = sample(60:90, 200, replace = T), Quiet = sample(20:60, 200, replace = T),
                       Owner = as.factor(rep(c(1,2), 100)))
summary(testdat1) # no values exceed 90
dtest <- dPlot(Recommend ~ Quiet, groups = 'Owner', data = testdat1, type = 'scatter')
dtest # plotted y-values reach upwards of 450
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I think I know the answer, but to make sure it is correct, I will need to clear up a couple of things.  First, what branch of rCharts are you using?  Also, `dPlot` should not accept scatter as a type.  Rather, it should use `bubble` for now (thinking about adding scatter as accessor to this type in future).  Dimple auto-aggregates  non-unique x,y,groups combinations.  This is a nice feature but can also be confusing.  As an example, if I take your code and just change to scatter it works as I would expect.  However, if I change to x as measure axis, I get aggregation but diff than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment but answer might be accomplished through this block of code:

```
require(rCharts)

testdat1 <- data.frame(Recommend = sample(60:90, 200, replace = T), Quiet = sample(20:60, 200, replace = T),
                       Owner = as.factor(rep(c(1,2), 100)))
summary(testdat1) # no values exceed 90
dtest <- dPlot(Recommend ~ Quiet, groups = 'Owner', data = testdat1, type = 'bubble')
#will aggregate as avg by default
dtest$xAxis(type="addMeasureAxis")
dtest

#add x,y, and grouping so now only will aggregate where x,y,and group is exact same
#if still a problem, could a unique id and group on that
dtest$params$groups <- c('Recommend','Quiet','Owner')
dtest # plotted y-values reach upwards of 450
```

Comment: Adding a sequence ID number as a group stopped the aggregation, thanks!